# meaning of 'call out that~' in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [the transcript of a podcast](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/1089175288).

> KIM: Yeah, I think what I really had to do was leave that behind. I
> think the recipes in here are incredibly irreverent (laughter) to,
> like, traditional or, you know, more common modes of cooking these
> dishes - but ultimately, to arrive at a reality, which is that even
> modern Korean cooks in Korea are really experimenting and challenging
> the norm. And I think people used to **call out** that I had used
> vegetable oil - or I didn't - that I didn't use vegetable oil in my
> cooking. But the only reason is that my pantry has olive oil. That's
> the only reason. It's not that Korean Americans all over the world are
> using olive oil. It's actually just that mine - my pantry has that,
> and my mom's pantry has that, too. And she's not sitting there in her
> Georgia kitchen worrying about what all the Koreans are going to think
> of this food that she's feeding her family.

I wonder what 'call out' means in the above context.

If it means 'to criticize someone about something they have said or done and challenge them to explain it' as in [a dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/call-out_1), I think the object of 'call out' should be 'someone' instead of that-clause.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I think the *exact* phrasing as cited is at least "clumsy". If I'd been writing it, I'd have used *...people used to **call me out for** using vegetable oil*. And I can't for the life of me understand why the actual text says ***I think*** there - the whole point of being "called out" for doing something "suspect / non-standard" is that the subject ***knows*** they're being criticised (not that they ***think*** they ***might*** have been criticised).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Oxford English Dictionary it is sense 7, of the composite verb ***to call out***.

*7. transitive. Usually in passive. Originally and chiefly U.S. To identify or single out (something), esp. as a problem or cause of trouble.*

One certainly hears it used in Britain, and I was previously unaware that it was "originally and chiefly US". One certainly hears it used in Britain in the sense of *complain*.